# Conformal Map from Upper Half Plane with Slit to Punctured Unit Disk

Tags: complex-analysis

Find a conformal map which maps $U_1$ onto $U_2$, where
$$U_1 = \{x + iy \in \mathbb{C} : y > 0\} \setminus \{iy \in \mathbb{C}: 1 \leq y \leq 2\},$$
and
$$U_2 = \{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| < 1, z \neq 0\}.$$

By conformal I mean being holomorphic and having a non-vanishing derivative on its domain.
Any hints? It seems like none of the standard conformal mappings simplify the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:)**

Consider Koebe function $K(z)=\dfrac{z}{(1-z)^2}$ from $\mathbb{D}$ to $\mathbb{C}-(-\infty,-\dfrac14)$. Then the function $\dfrac{1}{K(z)}=\dfrac{(1-z)^2}{z}$ from $\mathbb{D}-\{0\}$ to $\mathbb{C}-(-4,0)$. 
With rotation $-i$ about origin and factor $\dfrac14$ and translation $i$ you find a function. At last use inverse function for finding the final result.